# Creating a view inside a while loop and adding it to a layout outside

Tags: android

I have two cursors `cursor` and `cursordet` with the second one being inside the first. In
`cursordet`, I am creating two textviews, adding text to them and then I add these textviews to th row `tr`. I want this row to be added to a table layout outside the while loop of the coursor, but I get a cannot resolve symbol 'tr' on `tl.addView(tr);`. Is there a way to make `tr` public or make it an output the loop? Here's my code so far:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        TextView textOrdrID = new TextView(this);
        textOrdrID.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textOrdrID.setTextSize(25);

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERS_ID));

        while (cursordet.moveToNext()) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setClickable(true);

            TextView textOrdrProdName = new TextView(this);
            textOrdrProdName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textOrdrProdName.setTextSize(25);

            TextView textOrdrProdPrice = new TextView(this);
            textOrdrProdPrice.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textOrdrProdPrice.setTextSize(25);

            String prodname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERSDET_PRODNAME));
            String price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERSDET_PRICE));

            textOrdrID.append(prodname);

            tr.addView(textOrdrProdName);
            tr.addView(textOrdrPrice);
        }

        textOrdrID.append("Code:" + " " + id); 
        ordersdetLayout.addView(textOrdrID);
        tl.addView(tr);     

    }
```

Comment: Why you don't wanna to call `tl.addView(tr);` inside your loop?

Comment: You can create table row outside of your loop and then inside of it assign values for it.

Comment: @Anatol because I want tl to be added in a particular place in the activity and moving it would create many copies of it, which I don't want. I need the row to be created every time the cursordet loop is called. It will be created only once if I add it to the cursor loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this...

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        TextView textOrdrID = new TextView(this);
        textOrdrID.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textOrdrID.setTextSize(25);

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERS_ID));

        TableRow tr = null;
        while (cursordet.moveToNext()) {

            tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setClickable(true);

            TextView textOrdrProdName = new TextView(this);
            textOrdrProdName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textOrdrProdName.setTextSize(25);

            TextView textOrdrProdPrice = new TextView(this);
            textOrdrProdPrice.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textOrdrProdPrice.setTextSize(25);

            String prodname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERSDET_PRODNAME));
            String price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ORDERSDET_PRICE));

            textOrdrID.append(prodname);

            tr.addView(textOrdrProdName);
            tr.addView(textOrdrPrice);
        }

        textOrdrID.append("Code:" + " " + id); 
        ordersdetLayout.addView(textOrdrID);
        if(tr != null)
             tl.addView(tr);     

    }
```